# JavaScript to check for specific events

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `Wizard` on my page, and for one of the `WizardSteps` I have some JavaScript to enable / disable controls based on radio button selection.

This works fine in the first instance, however I also have a button which adds a row to a grid (and that row has a Remove link).  If I click the button, or the Remove option, then it does what I can only describe as a partial postback of the page and any disabled controls will now be enabled.

I've tried to catch anything on PostBack, but this doesn't actually get fired which is why I've described it as a partial one.

Is there an event in JavaScript that I can catch for this?  I figure if I can catch an event then I could try and make the controls enabled states persist.

EG I've tried to put some code to catch when the state changes for the control itself, but this doesn't fire.

```
    var myControl = document.getElementById('mainContentPlaceHolder_myWizard_myControl');
    if (myControl != null) {
        myControl.onchange = function () { DisableControl(this); };
    }

function DisableControl(myControl) {
// This actually does a lot more, but this is just for the purposes of showing some code.
   myControl.enabled = false;
   myControl.disabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this functions:

```
<script>
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(function() {
 //start request

});

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
 //end request


});
</script>
```